# Azure ARM templates - Stream Analytics identity.principalId as output

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-stream-analytics

I have a working ARM Template for a Stream Analytics job which creates it's own 'managed identity' which can be queried using AZ CLI, e.g.:

```
'az stream-analytics job show -g <resource_group> -n <stream_analytics_job_name> -o json --query 'identity.principalId'
```

(Deployment is via Terraform 'azurerm_template_deployment' module).

Added an ARM template output to return this key using 'listkeys':

```
    "outputs": {
        "principalId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs', parameters('StreamAnalyticsJobName')), parameters('ASAApiVersion')).identity.principalId]"
        }
    }
}
```

Now the ARM deployment fails as seen in the resource group deployments list with:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "NotFound",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n  \"message\": \"The webpage cannot be found.\",\r\n  \"details\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"404\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The webpage cannot be found.\",\r\n    \"correlationId\": \"<redacted>\",\r\n    \"requestId\": \"<redacted>\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the resource group Activity Log, under the 'Write Steam Analytics Job', there are failed operations for listkeys - none of which give any further clues.

'identity.principalId' found for this Stream Analytics job via https://resources.azure.com:

```
...etc...
  "identity": {
    "principalId": "<redacted>",
    "tenantId": "<redacted>",
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
```

Have also tried the following ARM template output with the same result:

```
    "outputs": {
        "principalId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs', parameters('StreamAnalyticsJobName')), parameters('ASAApiVersion')).principalId]"
        }
    }
```

Similar issues found but none for Stream Analytics:

- [Azure ARM templates : DocumentDB primaryMasterKey as OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486845/azure-arm-templates-documentdb-primarymasterkey-as-output)
- [How to return Redis primaryKey via ARM template output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665310/how-to-return-redis-primarykey-via-arm-template-output)
- https://devkimchi.com/2018/01/05/list-of-access-keys-from-output-values-after-arm-template-deployment/

Research:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-outputs?tabs=azure-powershell
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/powerbi-output-managed-identity
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please be more careful with tags. The "arm" tag is for the ARM microcontroller, not for Azure resource manager.

Answer (score 2):

Came across the answer elsewhere ([How to get Principal Id in app service using Arm template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127813/how-to-get-principal-id-in-app-service-using-arm-template)) as I was trying to obtain a principal ID not a key (my bad).

Using the following ARM Template output worked:

```
    "outputs": {
        "principalId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs', parameters('StreamAnalyticsJobName')), parameters('ASAApiVersion'), 'Full').identity.principalId]"
        }
    }
```